# MudTable Loading property set to false - loading indicator shows on ServerReload

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I have an issue that has been driving me crazy - using MudTable in Blazor and have the Loading indicator property set to false, Loading indicator does not show on initial load,  however any time ServerReload is call the Loading indicator still shows in the UI. No idea how to stop this from occurring

```
<MudTable Context="queueItem" ServerData="@(new Func<TableState, Task<TableData<DemoWorkQueueListItem>>>(ServerReload))" Striped="true" Loading="false" Dense="true" Hover="true" FixedHeader="true" FixedFooter="true" @ref="Table">
    <ToolBarContent>
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudSpacer />
        @if (QueueStatus is not DemoWorkQueueStatuses.Failed and not DemoWorkQueueStatuses.Summary)
        {
            <MudTextField T="string"
                          Immediate="true"
                          Placeholder="@Resource.Search"
                          Adornment="Adornment.Start"
                          AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search"
                          IconSize="Size.Small"
                          DebounceInterval="500"
                          OnDebounceIntervalElapsed="@(FilterList)"
                          Class="mt-0">
            </MudTextField>
        }
    </ToolBarContent>
    <HeaderContent>
        <HistoryColumns QueueStatus="QueueStatus"></HistoryColumns>
        <DefaultColumns QueueStatus="QueueStatus"></DefaultColumns>
        <SummaryColumns QueueStatus="QueueStatus"></SummaryColumns>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <HistoryRows QueueStatus="QueueStatus" QueueItem="queueItem">
            <MudIconButton title="Reset" OnClick="@(async () => await ResetDemoSearchRequestJurisdiction(queueItem.DemoSearchRequestJurisdictionId))" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Refresh"></MudIconButton>
        </HistoryRows>
        <DefaultRows QueueStatus="QueueStatus" QueueItem="queueItem">
            @if (QueueStatus == DemoWorkQueueStatuses.Sent)
            {
                <MudIconButton title="Reset" OnClick="@(async () => await ResetQueue(queueItem.DemoSearchRequestJurisdictionId))" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Refresh"></MudIconButton>
            }            
        </DefaultRows>
        <SummaryRows QueueStatus="QueueStatus" QueueItem="queueItem"></SummaryRows>
    </RowTemplate>
    <PagerContent>
        <MudTablePager RowsPerPageString="@Resource.Rows_Per_Page" />
    </PagerContent>
</MudTable>

    private async Task<TableData<DemoWorkQueueListItem>> ServerReload(TableState state)
    {
        AppStateManager.DisableOverlay = DisableLoading;

        //if (!DisableLoading)

        //{
        //    Loading = true;
        //}                


        GetDemoQueueQuery.SearchText = SearchString;

        GetDemoQueueQuery.QueueStatus = QueueStatus;

        GetDemoQueueQuery.PageNumber = state.Page + 1;

        GetDemoQueueQuery.RowsPerPage = state.PageSize;

        GetDemoQueueQuery.SortBy = GetSorting(QueueStatus, state);

        GetDemoQueueQuery.DemoConsumerId = DemoConsumerId;

        var responseWrapper = await DemoClient.GetDemoQueue(GetDemoQueueQuery);

        var tableData = new TableData<DemoWorkQueueListItem>();

        if (responseWrapper.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            if (responseWrapper.Payload != null)
                DemoQueueResponse = responseWrapper.Payload;

            tableData = new TableData<DemoWorkQueueListItem>()
            { TotalItems = DemoQueueResponse.DemoSearches.TotalRows, Items = DemoQueueResponse.DemoSearches.Items };
        }
        else if (responseWrapper.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized || responseWrapper.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        {
            Dispose();
            Loading = false;

            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/pages/error/401");
        }
        else
        {
            FailureCount++;
            SnackbarApiExceptionProvider.ShowErrors(responseWrapper.ExceptionResult);
        }

        if (FailureCount > 5)
        {
            Dispose();
        }

        Loading = false;

        return tableData;
    }
    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer
        {
            Interval = 5000                
        };

        timer.Elapsed += async (s, e) =>
        {
            if (await semaphore.WaitAsync(0)) // WaitAsync returns false immediately if the semaphore is currently unavailable
            {
                try
                {
                    DisableLoading = true;
                    await Table.ReloadServerData();

                    //await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
                }
                finally
                {
                    semaphore.Release();
                }
            }
            //await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        };

        timer.Start();

        base.OnInitialized();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a local bool field and assign that to the table's `Loading` property.

```html
<MudTable ServerData="@(new Func<TableState, Task<TableData<Element>>>(ServerReload))"
          Dense="true" Hover="true" @ref="table" Loading="pauseLoading">
    <!-- table body -->
</MudTable>
```

Then in your `ServerReload` method you set that local field to false. If you have other long waiting tasks after that then you need to trigger a `StateHasChanged()` after setting the field to false.

```cs
private bool pauseLoading = false;
private async Task<TableData<DemoWorkQueueListItem>> ServerReload(TableState state)
{
    pauseLoading = false;
    // notify state change if there are other long tasks
    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    //... rest of code
{
```

Not your code but [working snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wYmRbFHOEQhcQbEo)

Comment: When I modify your sample to refresh on a 10 second timer, I get the loading animation. https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/muGnvlmNrjWzJJxm

Comment: @codah after you set the loading to false do a statehaschanged. https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mYQxFFwtsEcUChlE

Comment: Yes that did the trick. I also have to ignore the warning "'Loading' should not be set outside of its component' (same as before).

Comment: @codah you might actually want to not follow this answer as I recently discovered that setting paramters using component reference is bad practice as it bypasses the setparameters lifecycle of the component.

Comment: @codah use a local field instead i've updated the answer to show how. https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wYmRbFHOEQhcQbEo